# how to select sum, and count from diffrent tables using multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to generate some big data from many tables, regarding filters, at there also i need to get the sum of some columns, and also counts of rows like example

i have 5 records

ID | NAME  | DELETED

1  | A     | 1
2  | A     | 0
3  | A     | 1
4  | B     | 1
5  | C     | 1

I have the query,

```
SELECT  p.name, sum(p.deleted) as del, count(p.id) as numbers from products as p
join other AS b ON p.id=b.id
```

The output i need is,

```
The sum of deleted records
```

NAME  | Deletion | Count

A     | 2        | 3
B     | 1        | 1
C     | 1        | 1

Comment: Have a look at Group By Clause..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ::

```
SELECT  
p.name, 
sum(p.deleted) as del, 
count(id)  as numbers
from products as p
join other AS b ON p.id=b.id 
group by p.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to join to get your result. This should work:

```
SELECT name, sum(deleted), count(1)
FROM products
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN deleted = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Deletion,
        COUNT(*) `COunt`
FROM    products 
GROUP BY name
```

OR

```
SELECT  name,
        SUM(deleted) Deletion,
        COUNT(*) `COunt`
FROM    products 
GROUP BY name;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d3a3/2)

Comment: can i use multi column grouping ? actually what grouping does ? can you define just little more for understanding

Comment: without `GROUP BY`, it will give you single record in the result list.